# req.params returns a part of the value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a React app that is posting to my Node/Express api. Posting is fine, but now I'm on delete and I cannot figure out why the req.params returns only a portion of the title string value. This seems like a fundamental thing that I am just not aware of, so go easy on me if it is a ridiculous question.

Here is my post, which works fine:

```
router.route('/movies')
.post(function(req,res) {
    var movie = new Movie();
    movie.title = req.body.title;
    movie.genre = req.body.genre;
    movie.actors = req.body.actors;
    movie.year = req.body.year;
    movie.rating = req.body.rating;
    movie._id = new Date().getTime();

    //save the movie and checkfor errors
    movie.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        } else {
            res.json({message: "Movie created!"});
        }    
    });

})
```

Here is the postman result of a GET after POST:

```
[
  {
  "_id": "586d94bf3175695e48f24fbd",
  "rating": "5/5",
  "year": "1981",
  "genre": "Thriller",
  "title": "The Godfather",
  "__v": 0,
  "actors": [
    "[Robert DeNiro, Al Pacino]"
  ]
  },
]
```

Notice the title string is "The Godfather". Now, here is my DELETE:

```
    .delete(function(req,res) {
        console.log('Title: ', req.params)
        var query = {title: req.params.title};
        Movie.findOneAndRemove(query, function(err, movie) {
            if (err) res.send(err);
              if(!movie) {
                res.json({message: "No Movie found with that title"});
              } else {
                res.json({message: "Successfully deleted Movie"});
            }
        });
    });
```

You will see my console.log in there, which logs as:

```
Title:  { title: ' Godfather' }
```

I have tried JSON.stringify the param.title etc but I think I am just doing something simply wrong here that is evading me the more I stare at the same code.

**EDIT**

Here is the client code making the POST. The DELETE route I am testing in Postman by using the following url:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/movies/:The Godfather


        handleSubmit() {
        let movie = {
            title: this.title.value,
            genre: this.genre.value,
            year: this.year.value,
            actors: this.actors.value.split(','),
            rating: this.rating.value
        }

        $.post( "http://localhost:8080/api/movies", movie );
```

Comment: Not sure if this has anything to do w/ it, but why do you stringify your actors as an array within an array? probably has nothing to do w /the issue at hand. Can you post the client code that is making the request?

Comment: Ive edited the post. For the actors, it comes in as a string from one text field.

Comment: seems like you info should be in req.body...not req.params. I could be off w/ that one, its late in the day

Comment: I visited that notion too, but when testing, req.body is empty and req.params has the {title: ' Godfather'}. So I am pretty sure that POST looks at the req.body and updates or deletes require a lookup to the db using the params sent in, hence the use of req.params

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DELETE is working just fine. My Postman url had a colon included in it, which had an impact that sent me in another direction. Basically, when I changed the original url from this:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/movies/:The Godfather
```

To this:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/movies/The Godfather
```

It worked just fine.

Comment: Yea, I saw that as well, but i thought that was how you defined your route, no how you actually fetched from the client. See what assumptions do...